# Loading mp4 video, textviews and images on UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want load huge chapter with contents like mp4 video, textview and images in TableView Cell. I can not take different tableview cell as user can select content from tableViewcell textview  for copy as a notes. Currently it takes huge memory. Please suggest any alternative solution. If I put the same on Scrollview  it is taking same amount of memory.

Any help and alternative approach is appreciated.

Thanks In advance ..

Comment: About memory, reuse cell will cut of some memory issues.

Comment: As I mentioned only one cell is there as I want to select the text from UItextview. I can not use more cells . One UItableViewCell loads whole contents .  I want to load 2nd chapter in next cell but it is crashing before loading or reusing cell

Comment: If there is only one cell than there is no need of `UITableView`. I suggest not to use `UITableView` instead use `UIView` and add subviews in it.